# Android gif - Convert Bitmap to Movie

Tags: java, android, gif

I'm writing .GIF support for my app.

Right now, I've got nice subsystem, that downloads large images and resizes them to fit the screen, taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

I need to find a way to convert [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) instance to [Movie](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html) instance.

There are methods:

```
Movie.decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length)
Movie.decodeFile(String pathName)
Movie.decodeStream(InputStream is)
```

Maybe solution hides in them, maybe not, but right now I don't see any path from one instance to another. Changing methods from android-dev page is NOT the solution (because cache is working for Bitmap instances only).

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: I did the exact opposite.  I created an app that would buffer unique PNG files and refresh the screen with the appropriate file at a given time.

Comment: You're trying to create an animated image from multiple BMP files? Are you needing to save the resulting product or just display the animation?

Comment: @TheCapn I need to display animation (using Movie instance) from downloaded compressed .gif as Bitmap instance

Comment: @Sparksis How did you do that? Could you share link or something?

Comment: @UnknownJoe did u get the answer if yes then please share your code.

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj Sorry, but I don't have any solution on this. I guess, that you will need to check file, that you download is it *.gif or *.jpg/png/... and so on.

Then, you will need a separate caches, one for gif files, and the other one for simple images. Then, whenever you're looking for your image, you check a specific cache, depending on your filename. 

Another problem, that it seems, LruCache won't just work for Movie instances, you'll need to organize gif cache on your own...Sad, but true(

Answer (score 0):

You have the method "draw" on the object Movie, what if you create a canvas of the size that you need, draw the Bitmap and then pass this canvas to the Movie object?

Or to get bytes from your Bitmap object:

```
Bitmap bmp...
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```